# How to write unit test cases in angular to check if multiple labels are present in my HTML page?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am rather new to angular and just started working in Unit Test case writing in angular. 
For the start i just want to check if my page has certain Labels having certain Text.

```
<div class="form-group row">
            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">Comments</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <textarea class="form-control h-85"></textarea>
            </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">City</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input class="form-control" type="text">
            </div>
</div>
```

When i wrote the first test case to check if there is a label having "Comments" it worked fine but when wrote test cases for both labels..

```
it('should render Comments in a label tag', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('label').textContent).toContain('Comments');
  });

  it('should render City in a label tag', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('label').textContent).toContain('City');
  });
```

Then it fails the second test and shows this ...

> Expected 'Comments' to contain 'City'.

I also tried this but the results were same

```
it('should render   in an anchor tag', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('label')).nativeElement.innerText;
    expect(compiled).toContain('City');
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `querySelector` method selects the first element it can find based on the query. I suppose you are looking for the `querySelectorAll`:

```
expect(compiled.querySelectorAll('label')[1].textContent).toContain('City');
```

If you just want to test if there is any label containing `City`, I guess this works as well:

```
const labels = Array.from(compiled.querySelectorAll('label')).map(
  ({ textContent }) => textContent
);
expect(labels).toContain('City');
```

Comment: And can we select specific labels using ID or anything?

Comment: You can use any CSS selector you might deem necessary the `.nativeElement` returns a normal HTMLElement on which you can call whatever you are used to call on it

Comment: Solved my problem! Thanks Alot.